# Stretching a point cloud at a certain angle; is this right, and is there a form not using trigonometric functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a group of points $x, y$ on an elastic sheet and need the new coordinates after "stretching" the sheet in one dimension by a fraction $a$ in a direction defined by $\theta$.

It should be easy for me to calculate the position of the points after stretching $x_s, y_s$ but I'm stuck.

*I am guessing* that the points move a distance away from the origin by a fraction $f$ where

$$f = \frac{a}{2} (1 + \cos ( \tan^{-1}(y/x) - \theta))$$

(which equals $a$ when $x, y$ fall on the line $y = x \tan(\theta)$ and zero when perpendicular to it) and then I can use

$$x_s = (1+f)x$$

$$y_s = (1+f)y$$

to get the stretched coordinates.

**Question(s):**

1. Have I got it right?
2. Can this be written in a simple form without the use of trigonometric functions? (no approximations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With stretch direction $\mathbf{\hat{s}} = \cos \theta \ \hat{x} + \sin \theta \ \hat{y}$, then $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{s}}$ is the distance of each point from the line of zero stretch in the $\mathbf{\hat{s}}$ direction. Extend it by a fraction $a$ further in the  $\mathbf{\hat{s}}$ direction:

$$\mathbf{r_s} = \mathbf{r} + a \ (\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{s}}) \ \mathbf{\hat{s}}$$

Here's a hexagonal lattice stretched with $a=0.2$ at an unsettling 80 degrees:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def stretch(points, a, theta):
    to_degs, to_rads = 180/np.pi, np.pi/180
    r_hat = points / np.sqrt((points**2).sum(axis=1))[:, None]
    s_hat = np.array([f(to_rads * theta) for f in (np.cos, np.sin)])
    print('s_hat: ', s_hat)
    dot = (points * s_hat).sum(axis=1)
    points_s = points + a * dot[:, None] * s_hat
    return points_s

def get_points(vecs, nmax=3):
    nmax = int(nmax)
    i = np.arange(-nmax, nmax+1)
    I, J = [thing.flatten() for thing in np.meshgrid(i, i)]
    keep = np.abs(I + J) <= nmax
    I, J = [thing[keep] for thing in (I, J)]    
    v1, v2 = vecs
    points = I[:, None] * v1 + J[:, None] * v2
    return points

r3o2 = np.sqrt(3) / 2
vecs = np.array([[1, 0], [0.5, r3o2]])
points = get_points(vecs, nmax=5)
points_s = stretch(points, a=0.2, theta=80)

plt.figure()
x, y = points.T
plt.plot(x, y, 'ok')
x, y = points_s.T
plt.plot(x, y, 'or')
for p, ps in zip(points, points_s):
    plt.plot([p[0], ps[0]], [p[1], ps[1]], '-b')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```